# VS Code launch: program does not exist

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

This is my file "test.c"

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 100
typedef int Element;
Element data[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
int top;

void error(char str[]){
    printf("%s\n",str);
    exit(1);
}

void init_stack(){
    top = -1;
}
int is_empty(){
    return top==-1;
}
int is_full(){
    return top == MAX_STACK_SIZE -1;
}
int size(){
    return top +1;
}
void push(Element e){
    if(is_full()){
        error("스택 포화 에러");
        data[++top] = e;
    }
}
Element pop(){
    if(is_empty()){
        error("스택 공백 에러");
        return data[top--];
    }
    
}
Element peek(){
        if(is_empty()){
        error("스택 공백 에러");
        return data[top];
        }
    }
    void print_stack(char msg[]){
        print("%s[%2d]", msg, size());
        for(int i = 0; i<size(); i++){
            printf("%2d", data[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
int main(void){
    init_stack();
    for(int i = 1; i<10; i++){
        push(i);
    }
    print_stack("스택 push 9회");
    printf("\tpop() ---> %d\n", pop());
    printf("\tpop() ---> %d\n", pop());
    printf("\tpop() ---> %d\n", pop());
    print_stack("스택 pop 3회");

    return 0;
}
```

and this is my launch.json:

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe build active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
```

and this is my tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

and I've got [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHLGD.png). It says: "*launch: program '<path to program except the path seprators are crossed out "W" characters>' does not exist*"

Can you point me where I'm wrong? I have installed c/c++&extension pack, themes, MinGW also.

Comment: 1) what if you move the project to your C drive? what if you use `${pathSeparator}` instead of ``\\`` in your launch.json?

Comment: I have tested your code on my machine and found an error on line 48. The `printf` function lacks an `f` at the end. Additionally, based on the screenshot you provided, you want to debug your code. According to the ` launch.json` file, you must have the gdb.exe debugger installed on your machine. If you don't have it, you should install it and ensure it matches the system path. You can refer to this link for instructions on how to install it: [Visual Studio Code - Configuring mingw-w64.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: @starball i've tried both of them and did not work. but thank you for helping me!!

Comment: @amd thanks for finding my typo error i fixed it and did not work either. i already have gdb debugger in my computer. i saw someone's folder on the internet and they had test.c and test.exe at the same time and i don't . Do you know that is what supposed to do??

Comment: you don't have test.exe? Did you run your build task yet? Note: you can also make your launch config run the build task before it starts. Use the `preLaunchTask` property of the launch config.

Comment: @starball omg thanks for helping me! it worked! i thought i build it and i did not... thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually run your build task. See the `Tasks: Run Task` or `Tasks: Run Build Task` commands in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

If you want the build task to be run automatically before starting the launch config, then use the launch config `preLaunchTask` field (see [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes) for more info).